# bash adding two comma to preserve blank field in csv

Tags: csv, awk, sed, tr

I need to load this in to a CSV file. And want to preserve the formatting in the spreadsheet by adding two commas at the end of a "-----" instead of one.

```
CASPER_CD_UNIAPP1_NETPROBE_PS      -----                07/12/2017 01:54:31  OI 45976571/4 -655
CASPER_CD_REFD_RESTRICTED_SYM_PS   -----                -----                OI 0/0
CASPER_CD_OPT_BILL_GEN_FEED_PS     12/12/2017 04:01:22  12/12/2017 04:01:22  OI 88970489/1 0
CASPER_CD_EOD_S3FTP_PS             07/20/2017 22:30:45  07/20/2017 22:32:27  OI 71030819/1 0
CASPER_CD_RPTS_SEND_PANAGORA_PS    11/28/2017 16:47:20  11/28/2017 16:47:22  OI 87295557/1 0
CASPER_BD_USDM_MAAS_PS             06/06/2016 21:00:39  06/06/2016 21:07:24  OI 24884239/1 1
CASPER_CD_USDM_MAAS_EXTR_LOAD_PS   06/06/2016 21:40:50  06/06/2016 21:45:57  OI 24884239/2 1
```

I have been using this one - liner:

```
$ grep _PS totalAutosysjobs.20171219 | grep OI | awk '{ print $1", " $2 ", " $3 ", " $4 ", " $5 ", "$6 ", "$7 ", " $8 } ' | tr "\-\-\-\-\-\," "\-\-\-\-\-\, \,"
```

The tr which usually works, did not

```
 | tr "-----," "-----, ,"
tr: unrecognized option `-----,'
 | tr  "'-----,'" "'-----, ,'"
```

escaping out the contents of tr does not work either , so I used

```
 sed -e s/'-----,'/'-----, ,'/g
```

Is there a way, in awk, or pure bash to add two commas to the end of "-----" do this inside of the script, instead of doing it to the results of a first command ?

Like:

```
    "if field $1 =~ "-----" please add two commas to end of "-----, ,"
     else " just add one comma".
```

Answer (score 3):

## Using awk

Try:

```
awk '{$1=$1; gsub(/-----/,"-----,")} 1' OFS=, inputfile
```

#### Example

```
$ awk '{$1=$1; gsub(/-----/,"-----,")} 1' OFS=, inputfile
CASPER_CD_UNIAPP1_NETPROBE_PS,-----,,07/12/2017,01:54:31,OI,45976571/4,-655
CASPER_CD_REFD_RESTRICTED_SYM_PS,-----,,-----,,OI,0/0
CASPER_CD_OPT_BILL_GEN_FEED_PS,12/12/2017,04:01:22,12/12/2017,04:01:22,OI,88970489/1,0
CASPER_CD_EOD_S3FTP_PS,07/20/2017,22:30:45,07/20/2017,22:32:27,OI,71030819/1,0
CASPER_CD_RPTS_SEND_PANAGORA_PS,11/28/2017,16:47:20,11/28/2017,16:47:22,OI,87295557/1,0
CASPER_BD_USDM_MAAS_PS,06/06/2016,21:00:39,06/06/2016,21:07:24,OI,24884239/1,1
CASPER_CD_USDM_MAAS_EXTR_LOAD_PS,06/06/2016,21:40:50,06/06/2016,21:45:57,OI,24884239/2,1
```

#### How it works

1. `$1=$1`

   This fools awk into thinking that every line has been changed.  As a consequence, awk will apply the new output field separator to every line.
2. `gsub(/-----/,"-----,")`

   Add a comma to the end of each appearance of `-----`
3. `1`

   Print the line.
4. `OFS=,`

   Use a comma as the output field separator.

#### Alternate awk

As suggested by [karakfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa), a variation on the above is:

```
awk '{gsub(/-----/,"&"OFS); $1=$1} 1' OFS=, inputfile
```

Here `"&"` means the captured text and `"&"OFS` means the captured text followed by the output field separator.

## Using sed

```
$ sed -E 's/-----/&,/g; s/[[:space:]]+/,/g' inputfile
CASPER_CD_UNIAPP1_NETPROBE_PS,-----,,07/12/2017,01:54:31,OI,45976571/4,-655
CASPER_CD_REFD_RESTRICTED_SYM_PS,-----,,-----,,OI,0/0
CASPER_CD_OPT_BILL_GEN_FEED_PS,12/12/2017,04:01:22,12/12/2017,04:01:22,OI,88970489/1,0
CASPER_CD_EOD_S3FTP_PS,07/20/2017,22:30:45,07/20/2017,22:32:27,OI,71030819/1,0
CASPER_CD_RPTS_SEND_PANAGORA_PS,11/28/2017,16:47:20,11/28/2017,16:47:22,OI,87295557/1,0
CASPER_BD_USDM_MAAS_PS,06/06/2016,21:00:39,06/06/2016,21:07:24,OI,24884239/1,1
CASPER_CD_USDM_MAAS_EXTR_LOAD_PS,06/06/2016,21:40:50,06/06/2016,21:45:57,OI,24884239/2,1
```

## Using bash

```
$ while read -a line; do (IFS=,; printf "%s\n" "${line[*]//-----/-----,}"); done <inputfile
CASPER_CD_UNIAPP1_NETPROBE_PS,-----,,07/12/2017,01:54:31,OI,45976571/4,-655
CASPER_CD_REFD_RESTRICTED_SYM_PS,-----,,-----,,OI,0/0
CASPER_CD_OPT_BILL_GEN_FEED_PS,12/12/2017,04:01:22,12/12/2017,04:01:22,OI,88970489/1,0
CASPER_CD_EOD_S3FTP_PS,07/20/2017,22:30:45,07/20/2017,22:32:27,OI,71030819/1,0
CASPER_CD_RPTS_SEND_PANAGORA_PS,11/28/2017,16:47:20,11/28/2017,16:47:22,OI,87295557/1,0
CASPER_BD_USDM_MAAS_PS,06/06/2016,21:00:39,06/06/2016,21:07:24,OI,24884239/1,1
CASPER_CD_USDM_MAAS_EXTR_LOAD_PS,06/06/2016,21:40:50,06/06/2016,21:45:57,OI,24884239/2,1
```

## Using python

Consider this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
with open('inputfile') as fhandle:
    for line in fhandle:
        print(','.join(word for word in line.replace("-----","-----,").split()))
```

Applying it to our input data:

```
$ python3 a.py
CASPER_CD_UNIAPP1_NETPROBE_PS,-----,,07/12/2017,01:54:31,OI,45976571/4,-655
CASPER_CD_REFD_RESTRICTED_SYM_PS,-----,,-----,,OI,0/0
CASPER_CD_OPT_BILL_GEN_FEED_PS,12/12/2017,04:01:22,12/12/2017,04:01:22,OI,88970489/1,0
CASPER_CD_EOD_S3FTP_PS,07/20/2017,22:30:45,07/20/2017,22:32:27,OI,71030819/1,0
CASPER_CD_RPTS_SEND_PANAGORA_PS,11/28/2017,16:47:20,11/28/2017,16:47:22,OI,87295557/1,0
CASPER_BD_USDM_MAAS_PS,06/06/2016,21:00:39,06/06/2016,21:07:24,OI,24884239/1,1
CASPER_CD_USDM_MAAS_EXTR_LOAD_PS,06/06/2016,21:40:50,06/06/2016,21:45:57,OI,24884239/2,1
```

## Further reading on awk

A good introduction to awk is the dated but well-written [Grymoire tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).  There is also [an awk wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AWK).  The definitive guide to GNU awk features is the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).  For advanced studies, see [Effective AWK Programming A User’s Guide for GNU Awk by Arnold D. Robbins (PDF)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf).

Comment: I would prefer `...gsub("-----","&"OFS);$1=$1...`

Comment: pretty amazing utilization of AWK So you think there is a way to do it in bash ?

Comment: @capser Bash method added to the answer.

Comment: @karakfa Yes, that may be less transparent to a newbie but it is decidedly better programming style.  Added to the answer.

Comment: @casper before you go delving into making the shell do something shells aren't designed to do and therefore do very poorly - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: @John1024, also reassigning fields after `gsub` is better, though not important here...

Comment: @karakfa _"also reassigning fields after gsub"_  Why?

Comment: depending on the replacement strings, reassignment of the fields may re-normalize the line, also set the new `NF`.  Might also depend on specific `awk` implementation though, which I can't verify now.

Comment: @EdMorton - I read the pages - my takeaway is - when dealing with a job where the file is smallest common denominator use the shell - when the jobs calls for going into the files and working, use a more efficient language, like Perl or Python.

Comment: @capser  In that link, Stephane was arguing specifically against looping in shell/bash. If you read further in that link, you'll find: _"When it gets more complex, and you really have to apply some logic to each line, awk is a good option."_  Like perl and python, both awk and sed can process whole files at a time and are efficient at it.

Comment: @John1024 - perl and python are well supported. when I type in AWK into amazon, I only really get the Oreilly book and another one made by the creators of AWK. How did your AWK skills get so good - where did you go to learn them.

Comment: @capser My favorite introduction to awk is the dated but well-written [Grymoire tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).  There is also [an awk wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AWK).  The definitive guide to GNU awk features is the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).  For advanced studies, see [Effective AWK Programming A User’s Guide for GNU Awk by Arnold D. Robbins](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf).

Comment: @capser For completeness, I just added a python3 solution.

Comment: @casper - If you need to find a a string matching a rexexp in a file then use grep. If you need to perform simple subsitutions on individual lines use sed. For any other text manipulation use awk. If you you need to do something that involves more than just manipulating text THEN consider perl or python or C or Java or some other language instead of an awk+shell combination. Personally I haven't found a use for perl or python yet but I've only been programming for 40 years so I'm sure the use case is right around the corner :-).

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about your input wrong - it's not space-separated fields, it's fixed-width fields.

With GNU awk for explicit handling of fixed width fields:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="35 11 10 11 10 3 11 999"; OFS="," }
{ $1=$1; gsub(/ /,""); print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
CASPER_CD_UNIAPP1_NETPROBE_PS,-----,,07/12/2017,01:54:31,OI,45976571/4,-655
CASPER_CD_REFD_RESTRICTED_SYM_PS,-----,,-----,,OI,0/0
CASPER_CD_OPT_BILL_GEN_FEED_PS,12/12/2017,04:01:22,12/12/2017,04:01:22,OI,88970489/1,0
CASPER_CD_EOD_S3FTP_PS,07/20/2017,22:30:45,07/20/2017,22:32:27,OI,71030819/1,0
CASPER_CD_RPTS_SEND_PANAGORA_PS,11/28/2017,16:47:20,11/28/2017,16:47:22,OI,87295557/1,0
CASPER_BD_USDM_MAAS_PS,06/06/2016,21:00:39,06/06/2016,21:07:24,OI,24884239/1,1
CASPER_CD_USDM_MAAS_EXTR_LOAD_PS,06/06/2016,21:40:50,06/06/2016,21:45:57,OI,24884239/2,1
```

The above will work regardless of the value of any of your data (so you don't need to test for `-----` or any other explicit values).